# Best way to keep a list in a wcf service memory

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a web application with a login system which uses a wcf service. The user type his username/password to login, then we create a unique token for the user and then the token is saved in the browser cookies to keep the user online. Everytime the user send a request, his token is sent along with the request. We keep all the tokens in a basic `List` in the service memory. Now, I'm asking myself if it is the best way to do this. Will iis recycle my app memory? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230961/data-persistance-in-web-services) question about keeping a list in a wcf service and it looks like I should avoid using a list in memory. What is the best alternative to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the App Pool housing your WCF Service is recycled, you will lose everything you've cached in memory, so you will also need a persistence fallback (e.g. RDBMS or NoSql database) which will be re-loaded on resumption.

You don't say what you want stored along with the token. If its just the string token, then a [`HashSet<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) might be best, and if there is other data, then a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, Whatever>` would work best.

Assuming that as users login / logout of your service that the token collection will need to be mutated, which means that [concurrency issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922985/concurrent-hashsett-in-net-framework) need to be considered, (you've got that with the `ConcurrentDictionary`)

And you'll also need to consider the effects of stale tokens - you'll want to remove / delete unused tokens (memory and database).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I understand well, the thing is to make a concurrent list and every time an item is added/deleted the same is done in the database. When the app recycle, I need to reload the list in memory. is that it?

Comment: That's pretty much it - out of interest, it seems you are paralleling something similar to Asp.Net `SessionState` - [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/21/using-asp-net-sessions-from-wcf.aspx) might be worth a read?